# editText is in focus, but the virtual keyboard dont open automatically using SHOW_IMPLICIT in AlertBuilder

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

When i use SHOW_FORCED the keyboard open, but when i closing the alertDialog, the keyboard change to text layout and does not hidden, 
keyboard only closes when the back button of the android is pressed, simulating back button in the code does not work.

And using SHOW_IMPLICIT dont open keyboard automatically.

***The commented code works but...

```
private fun insertItemQuantity(orderDetail: OrderDetail) {
    val modal = alert {
        customView {
            verticalLayout {
                title = getString(R.string.insert_quantity)
                val quantity = editText {
                    keyListener = DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789")
                    inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER or InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL or
                            InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED
                    showSoftInputOnFocus = true
                    isFocusable = true
                    isFocusableInTouchMode = true
                }
                positiveButton(getString(R.string.confirm)) {
                    val c = quantity.text.toString()
                    if (c.isBlank() )
                        toastCustomWarning(getString(R.string.field_cannot_be_empty))
                    else {
                        if (c.toDouble() > 0) {
                            RealmRepository.getRealm().beginTransaction()
                            orderDetail.quantity = c.toDouble()
                            orderDetail.uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
                            RealmRepository.getRealm().commitTransaction()
                            orderItemActivityViewModel.addOrderItem(orderDetail)
                        } else {
                            toastCustomWarning(getString(R.string.field_cannot_be_empty_or_zero))
                        }
                    }
                }
                negativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel)) {
                    quantity.clearFocus()
                }
                neutralPressed("Neutral"){

                }
            }
        }
    }

    //quantity.requestFocus()
    /*val inputManager: InputMethodManager =
            getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    inputManager.toggleSoftInput(
            InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,
            InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY
    )*/
    var inputMethodManager: InputMethodManager = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(quantity, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
    //inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY)
    modal.iconResource = R.drawable.ic_logo
    modal.show()
}
```

Comment: I am unable to understand what exactly do you want the keyboard to do?

Comment: when the alert is closed the keyboard does not close using SHOW_FORCED, I need it when the alert is canceled or closing, the keyboard disappears automatically.

Comment: So you want the keyboard to hide when the alertDialog is closed/cancelled, right?

Comment: Yes, but i need the keyboard open focus in editText when alert.show, and keyboard close when alert close or canceled.

Comment: The problem is Show_Forced open keyboard but not close, and Show_Implicit dont open keyboard but closing when alert close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about how to open keyboard but you can use this approach to hide the keyboard. I works quite well for me.

```
(getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as? InputMethodManager)
        ?.hideSoftInputFromWindow(findViewById<View>(android.R.id.content)?.windowToken, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Very good, works fine, the keyboard now is closing.

```
private fun insertItemQuantity(orderDetail: OrderDetail) {
    val modal = alert {
        customView {
            verticalLayout {
                title = getString(R.string.insert_quantity)
                val quantity = editText {
                    keyListener = DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789")
                    inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER or InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL or
                            InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED
                    showSoftInputOnFocus = true
                    isFocusable = true
                    isFocusableInTouchMode = true
                }
                positiveButton(getString(R.string.confirm)) {
                    val c = quantity.text.toString()
                    if (c.isBlank() )
                        toastCustomWarning(getString(R.string.field_cannot_be_empty))
                    else {
                        if (c.toDouble() > 0) {
                            RealmRepository.getRealm().beginTransaction()
                            orderDetail.quantity = c.toDouble()
                            orderDetail.uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
                            RealmRepository.getRealm().commitTransaction()
                            orderItemActivityViewModel.addOrderItem(orderDetail)
                        } else {
                            toastCustomWarning(getString(R.string.field_cannot_be_empty_or_zero))
                        }
                    }
                }
                negativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel)) {
                    val inputManager: InputMethodManager =
                            getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
                    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(quantity.windowToken, 0)
                }
                neutralPressed("Neutral"){

                }
            }
        }
    }

    //quantity.requestFocus()
    val inputManager: InputMethodManager =
            getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    inputManager.toggleSoftInput(
            InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,
            InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY
    )
    /*var inputMethodManager: InputMethodManager = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(quantity, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)*/
    //inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY)
    modal.iconResource = R.drawable.ic_logo
    modal.show()
}
```